# How to move collapsed row in kable to top left and remove from center hover?

Tags: r, kable

My script gives the result i show in the image. However i would not want my collapsed rows shown visually in the center. I would like to point them to where the arrow is or the first row of the column.

Do i change the valign argument?

```
df %>%
       filter(id==params$ID_NUM) %>%

     kableExtra::kbl(.,booktabs = T)%>%
kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", font_size = 9, latex_options = "hold_position",position = "left") %>%
collapse_rows(columns = 1:2,valign = "top")
```

[image]

Comment: i found adding `latex_hline= "major` in `collapse_rows` doing the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that adding latex_hline function at the end works

```
df %>%
   filter(id==params$ID_NUM) %>%

 kableExtra::kbl(.,booktabs = T)%>%
kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", font_size = 9, latex_options = 
"hold_position",position = "left") %>%
collapse_rows(columns = 1:2,valign = "top",latex_hline="major")
```